# Jquery wont select and add the style i want to my element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, styles

I have a control called message popover and this has a list of items. when the user clicks on an item in the list they get a description. inside this description is an icon. i want to move this icon down from the top by 5px.

when i run the application and then type

```
jQuery("#__icon0").css('marginTop', '5px');
```

in the console the icon moves to where i want it to. but when i place it in the code (init or some where else on the page, it does nothing and the icon doesnt move.)

does anyone know why?

Comment: Can you give us a more detailed snipped of your markup and css? Another idea: Maybee you want to apply the jQuery before the DOM is ready. Do you wait correct until the DOM-Ready-Event fires?

Comment: it still does nothing. i placed jQuery("#__icon0").css('marginTop', '5px');  in the init function and it doesnt do anything still.

Comment: Which init-function? It sounds good, but if the init-function is running before DOM is ready, it helps nothing. Can you give me a link to your page?

Comment: Why can't you do this in a stylesheet? It sounds like your code runs before element exists

Comment: how can i check if the dom is ready and then do this? or call after page loaded? or check if item is added?

Comment: You can find the docu and examples here: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I guess you should fire this after popup is loaded .. so within the popup script

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `.css('margin-top', '5px');` instead of `.css('marginTop', '5px');` ?